# rubymine resizes to full screen Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, rubymine

I have issue with ubuntu 12.04 where if i am working on Rubymine6 it auto resizes itself to full screen and than i can't see launcher panel or switch application even after closing Rubymine.

I have also tried to re-install Ubuntu and Rubymine6.0.3 but same issue occurs.

Please help.

Comment: the jetbrains forum would probably be the best place to ask this sort of question, but the current version of RubyMine is 6.3, not 6.0.3, so you might start there.

Comment: I have tried current as well as old version both.

Comment: Also while starting RubyMine i see a warning:  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0